# use a url variable to pull from a specific column

Tags: php, mysql

While pretty new to php/mySQL, I have experience in other languages. I have asked something similar to this question,however now I'm scratching my head at the "how" (i.e. commands.)

Basically, I'm trying to use a url variable to post a specific url
in my table.

```
id | name | url |
1  | aaa  | bbb |
```

If my url says "php?v=1", how can I check to see if 'id' & 'v' match then pull
the url from that specific column.

Here's a bit of my current code:

```
...

$v = (int) $_GET['v'];
$info['id'] = $v;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video") or die(mysql_error());

if($result = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    echo $info['id'] * "<br>";
    echo $info['url'];

}

?>
```

Comment: Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29   then move onto http://bobby-tables.com before you get into any trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use PDO or mysqli instead of the deprecated `ext/mysql`.  There's no need to select *everything*, just what you need via `WHERE`.

```
$v = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM video WHERE id = '" . $v . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably helped with MySQLs [`WHERE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/). Also consider using MySQLi or PDO instead of `mysql_*` functions since those are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php).

```
$id = intval($_GET['v']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM video WHERE id = $id");
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    print $row['url'];
}
```

- [`mysqli::query`](http://de3.php.net/mysqli_query)
- [`mysqli_result::fetch_object`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_object)